# How to share a property with React components?

Tags: reactjs, web, frontend

I'm new to React and I have a question about sharing properties from one component to another. For example, I want a parent component that has a "visible" function that I can pass to other child components.

Example:

```
CustomInput visible="true";
CustomDropDown visible="false"
```

I'd like to know the best way to do this, respecting good practices. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean. Are you wanting to pass a 'value' or a 'function' to the child components? If it's a function then you just pass it like so <ChildComponent visible={this.visible} />

Comment: ChildComponent was what I wanted. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Real simple.  You can pass methods as props.  Suppose you have a parent, or Higher Order Component (HOC), you could do something like this:

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
  logWord = (word) => {
    console.log(word);
  }

  render () {
    return <ChildComponent handleLogging={ this.logWord } />
  }
}
```

Then, in the ChildComponent, you simply access the method from props.  For instance:

```
class ChildComponent extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <div onClick={ this.props.handleLog.bind(null, 'Logged!') }>Click me to log a word!</div>
    }
  }
}
```

So, in your example, if you wanted a method that existed on the parent that updated a visibility attribute on your state, you could write:

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
    constructor () {
        this.state = {
            visible: false
        }
    }

    setVisible = (bool) => {
        this.setState({ visible: bool });
    }

    render () {
        return <ChildComponent updateVisible={ this.setVisible } visible={ this.state.visible } />;
    }
}
```

ChildComponent:

```
class ChildComponent extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <div onClick={ this.props.updateVisible.bind(null, true) }>Set me to visible!</div>
        <div onClick={ this.props.updateVisible.bind(null, false) }>Set me to invisible!</div>
          { this.props.visible && <div>I'm visible right now!</div> }
      </div>
    }
  }
}
```